# w1-gpio (Dallas 1-wire) not working on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Tags: gpio, ds18b20

I am using a setup with three DS18B20 temperature sensors in a 3-wire setup (using a pullup resistor of 4.7 kOhm from data to 5v) on a raspi prototype shield. This works fine with a Raspi model B+ V1.2.

Now I am switching to a Raspi Pi 2 model B v1.1.
The hardware connection as well as the GPIO hardware itself seems to be okay on the new board. I checked the GPIO pin 4 (default for 1-wire) through sysfs and verified that it can work as an output and as an input.

The old as well as the new board are run both under Raspbian.

What I tried so far:

First, I loaded w1-gpio using `sudo modprobe w1-gpio` (or alternatively through listing it in `/etc/modules`). Both ways it gets loaded (shown by `lsmod`). Additionally I loaded w1-therm the same way. However, the directory `/sys/bus/w1/devices` does not get populated indicating that the enumeration of the sensors does not work. There are no errors reported through `dmesg`. This behavior does not depend on enabling/disabling device-tree.

I gave it a second try using device-tree (enabled through `raspi-config`). I listed `dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4,pullup=1` or just adding `dtoverlay=w1-gpio`.
At the same time I removed any w1 entry from `/etc/modules`. After a reboot I noticed that w1-gpio was not loaded (not shown by `lsmod`). Again, `dmesg` gives no hints. Now I added dtdebug=on to `/boot/config.txt` and rebooted again. However, `sudo vcdbg log msg` gives no hints.

To be sure everything is up-to-date I upgraded the software and the firmware to the current level by

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

rpi-update
```

Now `uname` shows

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.48-v7+ #964
```

However this did not help.

One strange detail: after updating/upgrading the Pi the directory `/boot/overlays` contains additional entries. For example aside of `w1-gpio-overlay.dtb` there is now a `w1-gpio.dtbo`.

Now I am somewhat out of new ideas what to try next, but maybe someone can give me helpful information.

Thank you for any help.

Ed

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default 1-wire bus GPIO 4 all you need in `/boot/config.txt` is the entry

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

You may power from 5V but the data line pull-up should be to 3V3.  You may have damaged the GPIO and/or the Pi by exposing a GPIO to more than 3V3.

Comment: I checked again the loading of w1-gpio through device-tree: the result is taht it is not loaded, i.e. lsmod does not list it. Also, when I check /sys/kernel/debug/gpio gpio pin 4 is not in use. Additionally inspecting the signal at GPIO pin 4 dies not show any acitivity.

Comment: Sorry for typos, the 5 min edit window cheated me.

Comment: While I agree that connecting the pull-up resistor to 5 V is unwise the GPIO port 4 ist not broken - I checked the input and output direction.

Comment: Manually loading of w1-gpio using modprobe works in that it can be seen by lsmod. But GPIO port 4 is not in use when checked through /sys/kernel/debug/gpio. Unclear why. Additionally, checking pin 4 by scope shows no activity.

Comment: @Edul If the software is okay that leaves the hardware.  Hopefully a poor or loose connection rather than a duff device. Photo?